# I can not add tokens to the cluster when using

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet-geoman

I can not add tokens to the cluster when using  (библиотека leaflet)

*When I first load the page, I get all the markers and add them to the clusters - this is no problem. The situation is aggravated when I try to drag and drop to add new markers. These markers are added to the map, but clustered - they get into the cluster after a reboot*

`let dev = L.layerGroup();`

Adding to the cluster

`let markers = L.markerClusterGroup()`

Drag and drop to map when creating marker

```
map.on('pm:create', function(e) {
          e.layer.addTo( dev )
                 markers.addLayer(dev);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. The question needs a lot more sufficient information for us to help you.

Comment: This question appears to be about some framework or library you haven't mentioned, let alone tagged. Also, are those quotes real quotes or just a formatting error?